# ClassNotFoundException using ObjectInputStream and data class

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

so I have problem with my connection between `Server` module and `Client` module.

I have 2 data classes to read it from `ObjectInputStream` and send with `ObjectOutputStream`
unfortunatelly it can't find my data class, I tried implementing `Serializable` but it still didn't work. Please help and thanks.

Message.java (I use it for 2 modules):

```java
public record Message(String sender, String receiver, String content) implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

and the `Client` class from `Server` module, where it throws error:

```java
    public void run() {
        while(needToRun) {
            try {
                int amount = inputStream.available();
                if (amount != 0) {
                    ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
                    Message object = (Message) objIn.readObject();
                    receivedContent(object);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

it throws error when I try to read the object.

and sending `Message` method:

```java
    public void send(Message msg) {
        try{
            ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
            objOut.writeObject(msg);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` don't send the class along. You need the exact same class on both sides, at the same version (or you mess with serialVersionUID and have extensively tested conversion between versions which is _extremely_ tricky). You also need all 'dependency' classes - if your class contains a field of type `Foobar`, you need Foobar.class as well, and if Foobar in turn has a field of type `Qux`, you need that class as well, and so on. And all on the same version. There's a reason nobody uses OIS and OOS: They're nearly impossible to test and use.

Comment: so I have to create another module?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I have 2 modules (Server and Client) and each of them has data class implementing Serializable and do I have to create new module where I keep just 1 data class, which is used in Server and Client modules?

Comment: Yes. Both need to 'include' that module in their deployment. Or, have the server include the client, or the client include the server code, and make sure all classes (and classes for everything used in that class, recursively) is in the one that is included by the other.

Comment: but is keeping Server in a client safe and good? I already have client in Server module but still I need another to receive and add to my VBox

Comment: That's an opinion question. Nothing is going to go 'wrong' - whether it's good or bad design is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: but making server in client doesnt make really sense for me. I mean then you can create multiple servers or get access to server files and database login.

Comment: So, then make a 3rd module. Or rewrite it all to ProtoBuf or similar (and do that in... a 3rd module).